# How to test whole application api in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, testing

I have a multi-container application in .net build with docker. I want to test this application api with running project. I mean, I run a project with api and in other project i want to write tests that checks happy paths of each endpoint.

Is it possibile to do it? What is the name of this type of testing?

Comment: what is a happy path? Apart from this endpoint-tests can be done with any test-framework that support integration-tests.

Comment: I would call a happy-path "only" test in a microservice setup a negligent test.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, you could use Integration tests. A good start will be here at the Microsoft documentation.

[Integration tests in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: But i dont want to use test server but original application

Comment: @ŁukaszKaproń we have no clue about your application and your server. Please provide more info on your achitecture and what exactly you want to test.